draw into image with canvas jetpack compose
I am trying to draw with Kotlin and Jetpack compose on an image which I extract from the database.
I don't know exactly where the error lies.
The image opens normally. Also the drawing should work, because I get the notification with log.d in the logcat:

Drawing started at: Offset(484.8, 627.8)
Drawing at: Offset(484.8,627.8) Drawing at: Offset(462.4, 611.4) ...

But no drawing appears on the picture
Here is my code:
var selectedColor by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Blue.copy(alpha = 1.0f)) }

var strokeWidth by remember { mutableStateOf(30) } // Adjust stroke width as needed

val drawingPath = remember { androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path() }

AlertDialog(
    onDismissRequest = { onCloseDialog() },
    properties = DialogProperties(dismissOnClickOutside = false)
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text("Draw into Image")

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(300.dp)
        ) {
            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures(
                            onDragStart = { offset ->
                                drawingPath.moveTo(offset.x, offset.y)
                                Log.d("EditImageDialog", "Drawing started at: $offset")
                            },
                            onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                                drawingPath.lineTo(change.position.x, change.position.y)
                                change.consume()
                                Log.d("EditImageDialog", "Drawing at: ${change.position}")
                            }
                        )
                    },
                onDraw = {
                    drawPath(
                        path = drawingPath,
                        color = selectedColor,
                        style = Stroke(width = strokeWidth.toFloat())
                    )
                }
            )
            Image(
                painter = rememberImagePainter(selectedImageUri),
                contentDescription = "Selected Image",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            )
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    val uri = Uri.parse(selectedImageUri)
                    onSaveImage(uri)
                    onCloseDialog()
                }
            ) {
                Text("save")
            }
            Button(
                onClick = { onCloseDialog() }
            ) {
                Text("cancel")
            }
        }
    }
}

